# How to run multiple projects within VS 2005 as an instance?

Tags: visual-c++

I want to run multiple VS 2005 instance at the same time. Each instance has the different projects. But hardware restrictions limits me. Is there any way doing this?

I am trying to run from debug\program.exe. But it does not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly isn't working and what you want to do?

Comment: thanks it is partially solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the projects related?  You could wrap them up in a single solution and then keep one instance of Visual Studio alive.  Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: ok it works. But I need to debug all programs at the same time. 
I need to "Start without debugging". If I collect all project in one solution, I need to start all of them "Start new Instance" which opens the debug window. 
But. It is not important for me now. 

Thanks your reply.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your comment.  Do you need to 'debug' or 'run' all projects at the same time?  You said you needed to 'debug' and 'start without debugging'.  You can do this by going to the solutions configuration manager and enabling multiple startup projects when debugging.

Comment: Sure, just access the solution properties and specify multiple startup projects.  When you use the run command in Visual Studio, it will launch all of specified projects at once.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I need. Thanks alot.